# How can I get a product's status for a store?

Tags: product

This really does not seem like it should be difficult. I seem to be able to change a product's status for a given store, but not read it.

Below is a test script I've been using,

```
<?php
// Make this a Magento app
require_once '/var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

echo "Loading product ".$argv[1]."\n";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStore(2)->setStoreId(2)
->load($argv[1]);

echo "Product id is ".$product->getId()."\n";
echo "Product status is now ".print_r(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->getProductStatus($product->getId(),2),true)."\n";
// This always prints:
// Product status is now Array
// (  
//    [498] => -1
// )

echo "enabling product... ";
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), 2, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
echo "done\n";
// This actually seems to work, and change the status of the product in that store's view.

echo "Product status is now ".print_r(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->getProductStatus($product->getId(),2),true)."\n";
// This always prints the same -1 response as the first time
?>
```

And that's it. Pretty short and simple, and *changing* the product status in store 2 does appear to work, just not reading it.

Interestingly enough, both things do work if I use this:

```
echo "Product status is now ".$product->getStatus()."\n";

echo "enabling product... ";
$product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)->save();
echo "done\n";

echo "Product status is now ".$product->getStatus()."\n";
```

Except, after running that, in the store view all the attributes that had been set to "use default" now aren't. As a last resort that might work, but definitely not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I have a solution that does the job, but I definitely still would love to hear from anyone that can explain why I'm having to do it the way I'm doing it, and why the the two ways I have in my question don't work entirely right.

What I did, though, was simply to take the part from each that did work, and use them together:

```
echo "Loading product ".$argv[1]."\n";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStore(2)->setStoreId(2)->load($argv[1]);


echo "Product status is now ".$product->getStatus()."\n";

echo "enabling product... ";
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), 2, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
echo "done\n";

$product->load($argv[1]);
echo "Product status is now ".$product->getStatus()."\n";
```

Seems strange that I needed to, but it appears to do the job, so it's good enough for this one-off script.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue today. I found that this is because the `getProductStatus` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Status` is bugged.

Look at this code:

```
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    if (isset($rows[$productId])) {
        $statuses[$productId] = $rows[$productId];
    } else {
        $statuses[$productId] = -1;
    }
}
```

It checks if the query used to get the status found it. The query result is an array (because it's using `fetchPairs()`) with status as key and product ID as value. BUT in the code above you can see that it expects the product ID to be the array's **key**, not **value**.

Obviously the if condition fails and the product gets the status -1.

The solution would be to rewrite this function and insert `$rows = array_flip($rows);` before the `foreach` block.